# SQL Join on conceptually related but logically unrelated values

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, set

Consider the following dataset

**Ranges**

| id | first | last | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | C | T |
| 2 | A | C | X |
| 3 | B | E | T |
| 4 | A | B | Y |

**Letters**

| Letter | Type |
| --- | --- |
| A | T |
| A | X |
| B | T |
| C | Ts |
| F | Ts |
| D | T |
| E | T |
| B | X |
| A | Z |
| B | Z |
| C | W |

Where the caveat is that over time some types have changed, but are "equivalent" so to speak. Specifically in this case, type Y is also Z and type X is also W.
Also, types can have "subtypes", e.g. T is also Ts or Td.

Would this be the best way to join these tables if I want to output the letters in all of the ranges by type?

```
select distinct(letter), r.type from ranges r
 join letters l ON l.letter >= r.first AND l.letter <= r.last 
where l.type LIKE r.type + '%'
   OR (r.type = 'Y' and l.type = 'Z')
   OR (r.type = 'X' and l.type = 'W')
order by type
```

This is the correct output:

| letter | type |
| --- | --- |
| A | T |
| B | T |
| C | T |
| D | T |
| E | T |
| A | X |
| B | X |
| C | X |
| A | Y |
| B | Y |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/thD34WTx)

Answer (score 0):

```
with l as (
select  letter
       ,case when type = 'W' then 'X' when type = 'Z' then 'Y' else left(type,1) end as type
from    letters
          )

select   distinct letter
        ,r.type
from     ranges r join l on r.type = l.type
order by r.type
```

| letter | type |
| --- | --- |
| A | T |
| B | T |
| C | T |
| D | T |
| E | T |
| F | T |
| A | X |
| B | X |
| C | X |
| A | Y |
| B | Y |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/cpBNf77q)